# R: Converting Tidyverse into Base R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following R code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
ids = 1:100
student_id = sample(ids, 1000, replace = TRUE)
coin_result = sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
my_data = data.frame(student_id, coin_result)

my_data =  my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]
```

I want to count the number of "3 Flip Sequences" recorded by each student (e.g. Student 1 got HHHTH : HHH 1 time, HHT 1 time, HTH 1 time)
And the probability of the 3rd Flip based on the previous 2 flips (e.g. in general, over all students, the probability of a H following HH was 0.54)
Here is some R code that performs these tasks:

```
results = my_data %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result), lead(coin_result, 2)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  count(Sequence)
```

This code works fine on my home computer - but at school, we have an older version of R  (we have no internet connection, i.e. can not update/install new packages). When I try running this code on the school computer - I get the following error:

```
Error: Column 'Sequence' must be length 1 (a summary value), not 12
```

**My Question:** I am trying to find a different way to re-write this code - or perhaps write it in Base R.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the older version? Does it have dplyr installed, or is that part of the problem? What have you done so far to rewrite it in base R?

Comment: Related to your code (but not the problem running it on your school computer):  how are you counting 4 heads in a row?  Is that two 3-flip sequences as in (HHH)H and H(HHH) or just one sequence of three-or-more heads as in (HHHH)?  If the latter, you can use the rel() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the same result in a base R without any packages, you can do:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(table(unlist(lapply(split(my_data, my_data$student_id),
       function(d) {
         x <- paste0(d$coin_result, 
                c(d$coin_result[-1], ""), 
                c(d$coin_result[-(1:2)], "", ""))
         x[nchar(x) == 3]
         })))), c("Sequence", "n"))
#>   Sequence   n
#> 1      HHH 112
#> 2      HHT 106
#> 3      HTH 108
#> 4      HTT  93
#> 5      THH  97
#> 6      THT  97
#> 7      TTH  93
#> 8      TTT  94
```

This may be a little easier to understand in pipe format if you have a newer version of R:

```r
f <- function(d) {
  x <- paste0(d, c(d[-1], ""), c(d[-(1:2)], "", ""))
  x[nchar(x) == 3]
}

my_data$coin_result         |>
  split(my_data$student_id) |>
  lapply(f)                 |>
  unlist()                  |>
  table()                   |>
  as.data.frame()           |>
  setNames(c("Sequence", "n"))
```

Answer (score 3):

there's probably a conflict between `filter` function of `stats` & `dplyr` package that you have loaded in your workspace. Force your program to use `dplyr::filter` by doing

```
results = my_data %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result), lead(coin_result, 2)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
dplyr::filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
  count(Sequence)
```

to add to this you can investigate package conflicts in the future by using

```
library(conflicted)
conflict_scout()
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R` with `aggregate/stack`

```
subset(stack(table(unlist(aggregate(coin_result ~ student_id,
   data = my_data, FUN = \(x) 
    paste0(x, c(tail(x, -1), ""),  c(tail(x, -2), "", "")))$coin_result)))[2:1],
   nchar(as.character(ind))== 3)
```

-output

```
   ind values
3  HHH    112
4  HHT    106
6  HTH    108
7  HTT     93
10 THH     97
11 THT     97
13 TTH     93
14 TTT     94
```